# Can Sphinx be configured ---> to get same results as MySQL fulltext search

Tags: mysql, sphinx, full-text-search

I have a MySQL database table that contains multiple records of:

```
    "word-A" -- "words related to word-A"
```

For example: 
        chair -- furniture;table;office-chair;dining-chair

I am currently using MySQL fulltext match-against query (plain match-against, not boolean mode) to match a sentence against those words.

I am limiting results to 5. I am using fulltext indexes, and I am also loading these indexes in the cache.

This query gives me good quality results, but it is slow (100 ms or more).

I tried using [Sphinx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx_%28search_engine%29) for this. It is very fast, but results are not similar to those of MySQL fulltext query. Some results are same but usually in different order, others are totally different results.

For sentence matching purposes, is MySQL fulltext better than Sphinx?
Can I configure Sphinx to get similar results as that of MySQL fulltext search?

Currently I am using following configuration:

```
      SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2

      SPH_SORT_RELEVANCE

      SPH_RANK_PROXIMITY_BM25 (also tried SPH_RANK_BM25)

      stopwords enabled

      The min_word_len is set to 2 - same as that in my mysql config.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to recommend something without looking at your Sphinx configuration, reference data and a query.

It's worth to provide a couple of documents and a query that should match.